# How to extract value from URL and check cache to load data in varnish

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I have a scenario where my URL will be either contains a comma delimiter with value or without.
i.e. /api/parameters/XXXXXXXXXX?tables=*x0* or tables=*x0;x1;x2*.

now based on this URL I want to check in the varnish that, if URL contains multiple values as tables then separate that out and pass each table name in seperate URL (/api/parameters/XXXXXXXXXX?tables=x0, /api/parameters/XXXXXXXXXX?tables=x1, /api/parameters/XXXXXXXXXX?tables=x2) either to cache if miss then backend server.

then based on the response of this need to combine the result and return it to the client.
my question here is:

1. How to segregate the value from the URL and pass a modified URL to varnish cache or backend.
2. after returning the result I want to return it as a combined JSON object in a sequence of which it was originally requested with a comma delimiter(i.e. x0 result;x1 result;x2 result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to turn a single request into multiple subrequests in Varnish. Unfortunately this cannot be done with the open source version, only with the Enterprise version.

### vmod_http

https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/http/ describes how you can perform HTTP calls from within Varnish using `vmod_http`.

By sending HTTP requests to other URLs through Varnish, you can get multiple objects out of the cache and aggregate them into a single response

### No looping

The fact that Varnish doesn't have loops makes matters a bit more complicated. You'll have so set an upper limit to the amount of values the `tables` querystring parameter has and you'll have to check the values using individual *if-statements*.

### Returning the combined JSON output

Once you have fetched the results from the various URLs, you can create a JSON string and return it via `return(synth(200,req.http.json))`. Where `req.http.json` contains the JSON string.

This will create a synthetic response.

In *Varnish Enterprise* it is also possible to cache synthetic output. See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/synthbackend/ to learn more about `vmod_synthbackend`.

### Varnish Enterprise disclaimer

The solution I suggested in my answer uses Varnish Enterprise, the commercial version of Varnish. It extends Varnish capabilities with additional VMODs and features, which you can read about [here](https://www.varnish-software.com/softwareandvmods/). One easy way to try it out without upfront licensing payments, if you’re interested, is to spin up an instance on cloud infrastructure:

- [Varnish Enterprise on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Varnish-Software-Inc-Varnish-Enterprise-6-Ubuntu/prodview-atq2qasjkejio)
- [Varnish Enterprise on Azure](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/varnish.varnish-enterprise)
- [Varnish Enterprise on GCP](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/varnish-public/varnish-enterprise-6-payg-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks, @thijs feryn for your immediate and explanatory answers with solutions.